# How to use grep with matching stdout to list values in a file?

Tags: linux, grep

I have a file that contains a list of items and each item is on a separate line.

```
Apigee API,
BigQuery API,
Cloud Build API
```

I am using a gcloud command to list services `gcloud services list --available` to my terminal and the output is similar to

`bigquery.googleapis.com                       BigQuery API`

I am looking to run the gcloud command then grep for each item in the list above and output the associated `*.googleapis.com` into a new file but I'm having some trouble with getting a grep command to work.

I've tried something such as `gcloud services list --available | grep -F -f list.txt associatedfile.txt` but no output is seen in `associatedfile.txt`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output, not just the string `API` repeated everywhere. Make sure to include substrings and regexp metachars like `.` in places where you don't want a match since it's always trivial to match the strings you want but much harder to not match similar strings you don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your pipeline is

```bsh
gcloud services list --available | grep -F -f list.txt associatedfile.txt
```

then `grep` would read and filter the text from `associatedfile.txt`, not from the output of `gcloud`.  The `grep` utility will not read its standard input stream if given one or more pathnames as operands on the command line.

To filter the output of `gcloud` with `grep` and to write the resulting output to `associatedfile.txt`, use a redirection:

```bsh
gcloud services list --available | grep -F -f list.txt >associatedfile.txt
```

Also note that you will have to remove the commas at the end of each line, if these are not to be part of the actual search terms.

Comment: Thanks that worked well. I removed the list and made each string it's own line and I was able to get output into a secondary file.

Comment: That would fail if an item in list.txt was a substring of any string that appears in associatedfile.txt, e.g. `foo` exists in list.txt while `foobar` exists in associatedfile.txt.

Comment: @EdMorton `associatedfile.txt` is supposed to be an output file.

Comment: @rk92 Oh, you didn't have one search term per line? It looked like you had in the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda I see, I just meant the input you're searching in which I guess is the output of that command, not the other named file. Your first script has `associatedfike.txt` as the input file to be searched (missing a `>`) and I didn't think about the pipe before it.

Comment: @Kusalananda I had one search term per line but it was setup as a list with commas after the end of each line which I'm assuming was the reason why it errored. My last line didn't have a comma and I saw that there was only 1 result the first time I attempted it. Removed commas and got more results.

Comment: @Kusalananda Do you know how to get results back from partial matches? For instance if the gcloud command outputs `bigquerydatatransfer.googleapis.com  
 BigQuery Data Transfer API` and my input to search with is `BigQuery Data Transfer Service API`. I was unable to get a match for that and I'm not sure if it was due to the whole string not matching correctly.

Comment: rk92 just ask a new question. This answer does what you described in your question so it's reasonable that you've attempted it, but it's not the best starting point for what you're now asking for in comments nor to address the points I just raised regarding other input.

Comment: s/attempted/accepted/ above. Also, when you ask your next question tag it with awk instead of grep as this is now crying out for an awk solution.